# Liferay custom web services

Tags: web-services, liferay, portlet

I have some questions about the use of **Liferay** and **Lyferay web services**.

I have read the documentation liferay in particular the chapter 11 and 12 [(development/Documentation)](http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development)about the development (or use) of web services in Liferay ... but this documentation does not seem complete than what you can do (Searching on the web you can find different approaches regarding the use of Liferay).

So, here are my questions / concerns ...

Suppose you develop your portlets in Liferay .. This way I can interact with the '*core*' of Liferay and also write the front-end of my webapp that will be on Liferay. For example I can authenticate the user in my webapp using the Liferay API.

If I wanted to have an authentication system to access in my web app through my mobile app? 
I'm not crazy .. I also would like to have my own mobile app developed with native code. In this case I would expect to have a REST service to interact with Liferay.
I think that, in this case, I have to expose all of the functionality of my web app (portlet) also as web serivices

For example ... we can reason with regard to the user authentication..
I thought that you can:
1. Use the webservice native Liferay to access from the outside.
2. E'possibile to write my own web service.
   In this case, I'll have to write a portlet that is actually a webservice?
   When it might be convenient to implement a [CAS](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System)?

1. As Liferay works as regards the user session (for authenticated users)?
      In this case we will provide somehow username and password.
   If successful, I will have a token or session ID?
   Here I can read:

> To call the AXIS web service using credentials, you would use the
>   following URL syntax:
>
> ```
> http://" + userIdAsString + ":" + password + "@[server.com]:[port]/api/secure/axis/" + serviceName
> ```

I did not really understand if this should be done only to authorize the untente during login

I probably I am confused but the official documentation for Liferay is not my friend right now: (

Answer (score 0):

Yes you want to use custom portlet services in your native mobile app...

I have written very simple blog for doing exactly this:
Please follow the below link:

http://integrating-java.blogspot.in/2014/04/liferay-mobile-sdk-custom-services-part_4.html

By this you can use your portlet's custom service in your mobile native application.

And best part is you do not have to go through the authentication process if you use Liferay mobile sdk for this thing direct service call is enough.